# WordPress throwing 500 error when importing blogs from blogger

Tags: php, wordpress, import, blogger

I've got quite a large blogger site (6k posts, 23k comments). I've downloaded the blogger import tool from WordPress's site and installed it. The tool basically requests permission from your Google account to look up your blog data,then gives you the options to import them.

The import starts, it gets all the blog posts, and does about 3.5k comments, then appears to stop. I've opened my browsers console and it's saying

```
public_html/wp-admin/admin.php?import=blogger&noheader=true
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If i try to reimport them again, it does the same thing.

Does anyone know solutions to this?

Comment: Can you have a look at the error logs of apache/php related to this request?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

If you use Plesk Panel or CPnael, WHM...

Change the PHP Settings :

Memory Limit : 128M

Max Execution Time : 10000

Post Max Size : 16M

Upload Max Filesize : 16M

and import data success!

Detail : [WordPress Importing problem](http://www.karabulut.co/wordpress-icerik-aktarma-import-hatasi/)

Comment: Updating the max execution time to 10000 worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I switch from a physical server to a virtual server and run into the same problem and found a solution.

The reason why you get this error is because the php scripts reading the xml file and making the mysql database entries might be too slow for the server time executing levels set. My benchmark for 2000posts xml (4MB file) 20secs. process time for a physical server and around 5min for the same upload on a virtual server. Virtual servers are processing slow and at the same time have tiny process time limits. This throws 500 internal server errors, simple not because your php script is wrong, but the process time ist too long.
To change this you have to edit these limits and enter higher (way higher) numbers, in these files:

1) php.ini: set "max execution time" up (at least to 5-10 minutes, depending on estimated processing time)

2)fcgid.conf: set "FcgidIOTimeout" to at least 90 or 120 
You find this file here: /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf or for Debian systems here /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf

Obviously these changes require root access to the server. If you don't have ask your hosting provider.

For me only changes in fcid.conf solved the problem and a coffee break waiting for the upload. I checked mysql database in the meantime and saw there are more files in wp_post... So I knew, its working... but slowly...

Answer (score 0):

in functions.php

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
@ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize', '256M');
```